# How to cancel dialog prompted by find/replace?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm attempting to migrate some worksheets into a new workbook. These worksheets have references to other worksheets in the pre-migration workbook. My plan is to replace the "['filename.xlms'....." with "#REF!" so that the user can input the new workbook filename in a config tab and hit a button to find/replace all #REF! with the new filename to reference. I've got that function working properly but I'm having trouble simply find/replacing all the current/pre-migration workbook references with #REF!. I'm using this code and it appears to be working properly.

```
Sub Find_Replace_Migrate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

Set sourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
sourceBook.Activate

Sheets("new_worksheet_in_new_workbook").Select
Sheets("new_worksheet_in_new_workbook").Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="old_workbook.xlsm", Replacement:="#REF!", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However...every time the script replaces the good known working workbook reference with #REF!, it asks for me to find and search for that workbook in my file system (a prompt appears to 'open' a workbook, or simply cancel the action). Now this would be fine if I had 5-10 find/replaces, but I've got about 90,000 cells to find/replace per worksheet and I've got about 12-15 worksheets to migrate over...

Is there a way to disallow these prompts or a way to automatically cancel this action? Thanks!

Comment: There's built-in Excel functionality to update links, right? Are you reinventing the wheel, or am I missing something?

Comment: The name of the file can change depending on whatever the vendor names it to and the location will never be the same. That is why I have a field for the vendor to input the source workbook filename and a function to find replace the #REF! with the vendor named source workbook. These worksheets existed on the source workbook previously but I could not keep the end users from screwing up the excel formulas so I'm moving them to an second workbook that the end users will not see and the vendors will utilize.

Comment: How about `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: @TimStack Yes this was half of what I needed. I must have found this exactly when you commented. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some continued researching I found what I needed.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False       
Application.EnableEvents = False
```